# Angular typescript : variable content is undefined after assignment

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, api, http

On my ngOnInit method I'm calling my api to get user's information and set it into a currentUser variable, when trying to patch the content of currentUser into a from group I got:

```
this.currentUser is undefined
```

.ts file

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
      currentUser: any;
      user: FormGroup;
      firstName: any;
      lastName: any;
      cities: any[];
      fileToUpload: any;
      avatarPath: any;
      avatarURL: any;
      returnUrl: any;

      counts: any;

      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router,
        private toastr: ToastrService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private fb: FormBuilder
      ) {
        this.createForm();
      }

      createForm() {
        this.user = this.fb.group({

          firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')]),
          lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')]),
          email: new FormControl('', [Validators.email]),
          gender: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          birthDate: new FormControl(''),
          phone: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
          oldPassword: new FormControl(''),
          password: new FormControl(''),
          profession: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')]),
          address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          city: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
          postalCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1000), Validators.max(10000)])
        }, )

      }


      ngOnInit() {    
        this.http.get('api/user').subscribe(user => {
          this.currentUser = user;
          localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
        });
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
        this.http.get('api/cities').subscribe((cities: any[]) => {
          this.cities = cities;
        });
        this.user.patchValue({
          firstName: this.currentUser.firstName,
          lastName: this.currentUser.lastName,
          email: this.currentUser.email,
          profession: this.currentUser.profession,
          gender: this.currentUser.gender,
          birthDate: this.currentUser.birthDate,
          phone: this.currentUser.phone,
          oldPassword: this.currentUser.oldPassword,
          password: this.currentUser.newPassword,
          address: this.currentUser.address,
          postalCode: this.currentUser.postalCode,
          city: this.currentUser.city._id
        });
       }

     }
```

how to fix that and patch my variable content into the user formGroup ?
even when I try to log the content of currentUser outside the http get it's undefined !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have async problem. this.user.patchValue works before your get request. U can take this part into get method.

```
 this.http.get('api/user').subscribe(user => {
       this.currentUser = user;
       localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
       localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
       this.user.patchValue({
          firstName: this.currentUser.firstName,
          lastName: this.currentUser.lastName,
          email: this.currentUser.email,
          profession: this.currentUser.profession,
          gender: this.currentUser.gender,
          birthDate: this.currentUser.birthDate,
          phone: this.currentUser.phone,
          oldPassword: this.currentUser.oldPassword,
          password: this.currentUser.newPassword,
          address: this.currentUser.address,
          postalCode: this.currentUser.postalCode,
          city: this.currentUser.city._id
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, can you explain the concept of this async pbm and how to handle and work with ?

Comment: Request to api works  asyncronusly. It means it continues but your next step codes doesn't wait it . So this.user.patchValue try to fill its data before you take data from your api.

Comment: So to handle this problem you can make your next step processes which are needed your data from api in subsribe method. Because there will be always data  there. And I suggest you also to use if condition that you took data from api with service